# Using an imported module's function

Tags: python, function, import, module

I have a module called menu from which I want to call various other modules.

```
def firststuff():

    import Add_data
    import Edit_data
    import View_Class
    import delete_data
    count1=0
    count2=0
    count3=0
    count4=0
    menu(count1,count2,count3,count4)


def menu(count1,count2,count3,count4):

    print("1.Add data")
    print("2.Edit data")
    print("3.View data")
    print("4.Delete Data")
    choice= input("Please select your choice")
    if choice == "1":
        Add_data.importantstuff()
    elif choice == "2":
        Edit_data()
    elif choice == "3":
        View_data()
    elif choice == "4":
        Delete_data()
    else:
        print("Sorry, this is not a valid input. Please try again")
        menu()        

firststuff()
```

I have not finished coding the rest of the options and it probably isn't the most elegant code, but I just want it to work. When option 1 is selected, it comes up with:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'importantstuff'
```

---

```
## This is my Add_data module

def importantstuff():

    import sqlite3
    Menu()

def Menu():

    print("1.Add classes")
    print("2.Add a new student")
    print("3. Add grades")                   
    print("4. Go back")
    menu= input("Please select a number")
    if menu =="1":
        Add_class()
    elif menu == "2":
        Add_new_student()
    elif menu =="3":
        ID =Add_grades()

        whereGrade(ID)

    elif menu =="4":
        import Menu
    else:
        print("That is an invalid input, please try again")
```

So, as you can see the `Add_data` module does have a function `importantstuff`. I'm probably being extremely dim, but i can't figure out why it isn't running the function?

Comment: Your error message is very misleading based on that data you've shown us. If anything, it would read `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'importantstuff'` (notice: `'module'` instead of `'function'`). None of this makes much sense as it stands and I don't see how we can decipher the mystery with the information we've been given.

Comment: The error is AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'importantstuff' (not 'module') which is partly why i am confused